# How to toggle plus & minus with ReactJs submenu?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have ReactJS submenu this is working fine but now I want to toggle `plus` & `minus` icons, how can I do this?

My Code:-

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faPlus } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

const Home = (props) => {
  const [subMenuOpen, setSubMenuOpen] = useState(-1);
  const toggleMenu = (x) => setSubMenuOpen(subMenuOpen === x ? -1 : x)
  return (
    <>
      <div className="submenu-list">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="#" onClick={() => toggleMenu(0)}>
                test <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} />
              </Link>

              <ul class={`sub-menu ${subMenuOpen === 0 ? "is-open" : ""}`}>
                <li class="menu-item">Sub-Item 1</li>
                <li class="menu-item">Sub-Item 2</li>
                <li class="menu-item">Sub-Item 3</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="#" onClick={() => toggleMenu(1)}>
                test <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} />
              </Link>

              <ul class={`sub-menu ${subMenuOpen === 1 ? "is-open" : ""}`}>
                <li class="menu-item">Sub-Item 1</li>
                <li class="menu-item">Sub-Item 2</li>
                <li class="menu-item">Sub-Item 3</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
    )
}
```

```css
.submenu-list{ background: #ccc; width: 200px;}
.submenu-list ul{ margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
.submenu-list ul li{ list-style: none; text-align: left; padding: 0px 20px; line-height: 32px;}
.submenu-list ul li a{ color: #000; text-decoration: none; display: block;}
.submenu-list ul li a svg{ float: right; margin-top: 8px;}
.sub-menu { display: none;}
.sub-menu.is-open { display:block;}
```

Comment: I didn't really understand your question, can you clarify ? Do you want to display `faPlus` when submenu is closed and minus when submenu is opened ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `FontAwesomeIcon` component for first menu to `<FontAwesomeIcon icon={subMenuOpen === 0 ? faMinus : faPlus} />` and for second menu to `<FontAwesomeIcon icon={subMenuOpen === 1 ? faMinus : faPlus} />` . Here's the full code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faPlus, faMinus } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

const Home = (props) => {
  const [subMenuOpen, setSubMenuOpen] = useState(-1);
  const toggleMenu = (x) => setSubMenuOpen(subMenuOpen === x ? -1 : x);
  return (
    <>
      <div className="submenu-list">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="#" onClick={() => toggleMenu(0)}>
              test{" "}
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={subMenuOpen === 0 ? faMinus : faPlus} />
            </Link>

            <ul class={`sub-menu ${subMenuOpen === 0 ? "is-open" : ""}`}>
              <li class="menu-item">Sub-Item 1</li>
              <li class="menu-item">Sub-Item 2</li>
              <li class="menu-item">Sub-Item 3</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="#" onClick={() => toggleMenu(1)}>
              test{" "}
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={subMenuOpen === 1 ? faMinus : faPlus} />
            </Link>

            <ul class={`sub-menu ${subMenuOpen === 1 ? "is-open" : ""}`}>
              <li class="menu-item">Sub-Item 1</li>
              <li class="menu-item">Sub-Item 2</li>
              <li class="menu-item">Sub-Item 3</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Home />
    </Router>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit dark-voice-6kr5d]

Answer (score 0):

you can do that using hooks

```js
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false) // false is when the menu is closed, open for when the menu is opened

{open ? (
  // in this case, the menu is not opened and show plus icon
) : (
  // in this case, the menu is opened and show minus icon
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a simpler way to do it is to decompose your list items into another component and manage its state internally in the component. It will help you to collapse/expand easily

Here I have refactored your code, do check it out.

- It will help you break your code into a separate component.
- change your icon conditionally
- Manage your collapse/Expand functionality in a simpler way.
- Organize your data

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faPlus, faMinus } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  //just added this to structure your data dynamically at one place, you can directly pass the values in props.
  const menuDetails = [
    {
      name: "Test 1",
      items: ["Sub-Item 1", "Sub-Item 2", "Sub-Item 3"],
      link: "#"
    },
    {
      name: "Test 2",
      items: ["Sub-Item 1", "Sub-Item 2", "Sub-Item 3"],
      link: "#"
    }
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <div className="submenu-list">
          <ul>
            <MenuItem
              link={menuDetails[0].link}
              menuItems={menuDetails[0].items}
              name={menuDetails[0].name}
            />
            <MenuItem
              link={menuDetails[1].link}
              menuItems={menuDetails[1].items}
              name={menuDetails[1].name}
            />
          </ul>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

const MenuItem = ({ link, menuItems, name }) => {
  //using false to make it collapse by default
  const [subMenuOpen, setSubMenuOpen] = useState(false);
  //everytime you call this, it will toggle the state (expand if it's collapsed and collapse if it's expanded)
  const toggleMenu = () => setSubMenuOpen(!subMenuOpen);
  return (
    <li>
      <Link to="#" onClick={() => toggleMenu()}>
        {/* if the submenu is open(expanded) it will show minus otherwise plus(on expanded state) */}
        {name} <FontAwesomeIcon icon={subMenuOpen ? faMinus : faPlus} />
      </Link>

      <ul className={`sub-menu ${subMenuOpen ? "is-open" : ""}`}>
        <li className="menu-item">Sub-Item 1</li>
        <li className="menu-item">Sub-Item 2</li>
        <li className="menu-item">Sub-Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  );
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-cherry-sz9j5